# PHP If logic being skipped?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm having some problems with this login script, I've already had someone else look it over for me and we cannot seem to figure out what the issue is.

What's happening is when a user tries to login, if the the username is correct it will check if the password is correct and if the password is correct it updates the last access date and redirects like it is supposed to. However if the username is correct and the password is incorrect. It should empty out the password, and let the user know the password they entered is incorrect.
What actually happens when the password is incorrect, is it is skipping to the outermost else statement, and emptying out the username and password and saying there is an issue...whether or not the username entered is correct (regardless of whether or not the password is right).

I have no idea what is happening here, and hopefully someone can help me shed some light on it.

Thank you!

```
    $selectUser = pg_prepare($dbConnection, "selectuser_query", 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1 AND password = $2');

    <?php 

    $error = "";
    $username_error = "";
    $password_error = "";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") 
    {
        $login = "";
        $password = "";
    } 
    else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        $login = trim($_POST["login"]); 
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

        if(!isset($login) || $login == "")
        {
            $username_error = "You must enter your user name to login!";
        }

        if (!isset($password) || $password == "") 
        {
            $password_error = "You must enter your password to login!";
        }

        if(($error == "") && ($password_error == "") && ($username_error == ""))
        { 
            $selectUser = pg_execute($dbConnection, "selectuser_query", array("$login", "$password"));

            if($login == pg_fetch_result($selectUser, "user_id"))
            {
                if($password == pg_fetch_result($selectUser, "password"))
                {
                    $date = date("n-j-Y");

                    $updateDateAccess = pg_execute($dbConnection, "updatedate_query", array("'$date'", "$login"));

                    header('Location: ./welcome.php');  
                }
                else 
                {
                    $password = "";
                    $error = "The password is incorrect. Please try again.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $login = "";
                $password = "";
                $error = "The username/password is incorrect. Please try again.";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but you do not want to distinguish in the messages between an incorrect user name and an incorrect password.  Doing so allows an attacker to guess (or confirm) user names, then attack passwords for known user names.

Comment: You need to post `selectuser_query` - I'm 99% sure it's doing a query that checks both the username and password, which results in no records being returned if the password is incorrect. Thus, the next `if` condition isn't satisfied.

Comment: This is not secure in any sense. You're storing passwords in plain-text (unhashed) so an admin/hacker can see all passwords in the database. You should also learn about salting hashes

Comment: Apart from what they all said, you're never printin any of the errors, therefore what were you expecting? :). You're storing the errors, but you're never printing any error.

Comment: your bug is actually saving you from username guess attack!!!

Comment: You could also tidy up your code a little. Why check username, and if ok, then password? Check username AND password both OK. Both are required to return a TRUE and move on, so check both at the same time. Also, you have run on `if`s, in that not using `elseif`, you allow more than one `IF` to be TRUE and return multiple potential text, which depending on the scenario is not ideal. Also, don't tell the user which of usr or pass was incorrect. They can guess easily that way (i.e. oh, so username was ok, let's keep trying for their password...)

Comment: Read this, then start over: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: What is the datatype of `$selectUser` ? It is possible that it can hold more than one rows. In that case, you must check for the number of rows in it first and then check `user_id` from first row only. Just for example, we can do this with arrays lik this:  `$selectUser[0]['user_id']`.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you guys are saying. Normally I would hash, and not return different messages but this is for a school assignment and it was the was my Professor wanted it done.

Comment: @AaronWickens Fair enough... But you might want to make sure (politely) that your professor knows he's teaching bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1 AND password = $2
```

It checks both the username and password, which results in no records being returned if the password is incorrect. Thus, the next `if` condition isn't satisfied:

```
$selectUser = pg_execute($dbConnection, "selectuser_query", array("$login", "$password")); // no records

if($login == pg_fetch_result($selectUser, "user_id")) // not satisfied, because there are no records
{
    // ...
}
else // this runs
{
    $login = "";
    $password = "";
    $error = "The username/password is incorrect. Please try again.";
}
```

What you want to do is run a query that retrieves the (salted and hashed) password for a given username, then check the password in your application logic.

Also, as others have pointed out in the comments, this is not a good way to store passwords or respond to incorrect info. It looks like the passwords are in plain text, but they should be hashed and salted. Also, you should not tell the user which part of the information was incorrect; otherwise, you let an attacker determine valid usernames and then focus on brute-forcing those.

Comment: I edited my initial post and added the pg_prepare that prepares my query, right up at the top of the code. I posted it outside of the PHP tags (it is in the proper tags in the code itself, but it is help in a different file).

Comment: That's definitely your problem: only a match for both username and password will be selected, so if the password is incorrect, you get zero rows.

Comment: No, it would be one of two things: (1) use the query you have, but just respond that the username and password combination wasn't found (don't distinguish between wrong username and wrong password) or (2) only do the `SELECT` based on the username, then check the password in your application logic. Either way, don't distinguish between wrong username and wrong password.

Comment: Okay thank you. I changed my prepare/execute to check the row where the user_id is $login, instead of user_id and password. I understand now! And this is for an assignment in class, this is the only reason I'm distinguishing between wrong username/password, it was a requirement in our rules for this one.